# How to remove Horizontal Tabs from Word Documents With VBA

Tags: vba

Is it possible to remove Horizontal tabs from a Microsoft Word Document with the use of VBA? I have learnt to remove spaces. But that does not work with trying to remove Horizontal Tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have myself solved my problem trying to delete Tabs from Word documents with VBA. This is how I have done it. The code presented below takes care of removing extra spaces (if there are more than one space between words) as well as Tabs from Word document.

```
 Sub Blank_Spaaces_Unwanted_Remove()

    Dim ospace As Characters
    Set ospace = ActiveDocument.Characters

    Dim xspace As Integer
    xspace = 0

    For Each aspace In ospace
        If aspace <> Chr(32) Then ' Chr(32) equals space.
            xspace = 0
        End If
        If aspace = Chr(32) Then
            xspace = xspace + 1
            If (xspace = 2) Then
                aspace.Delete
                xspace = 1
            End If
        End If
        If aspace = vbTab Then
            aspace.Delete
        End If
    Next aspace


 End Sub
```